# Can I use opencv cvResize() function on my own custom data 2D array? If yes How?

Tags: opencv, resampling

Objective:

I am trying to use openCV function cvResize() to resample a 2D array.[I have a working code in opencv using cvResize, I know its usage] But the input 2D array which I want to resample is not any image read by openCV using cvLoadImage() instead -

1.I would want to read the 2D array from a text file I have. That file has floating point values, in it. I would open that file in this test code using opencv library, read the values in a 2D array of float.

2.Then use cvResize() to resize it. First I want to downsample it - width/2, height/2.

3.Then I want to upsample it by 4 - width*4, height*4. This is my final 2D array.

4.Store this final 2D array to a text file as floating point values.

5.Basically I want to use the Bilinear interpolation logic used by OpenCV, but on my own data. What path/which file can I see the code for cvResize()?

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: @karlphilip - I posted a acomment there in my earlier question. I did not need cvCopy(). Pls see the comment there and let me know your inputs.

Comment: @karlphilip - Any pointers on this question?

Comment: Thanks. I added a path for you to follow. I suspect you are able to fill the missing pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here seems to be that you are using a data type (2D array) to store the data read from the file, that is not compatible with what `cvResize()` works with (it's `IplImage*` remember?).

If you are using the C interface of OpenCV (and by watching your other questions I know you are), after successfully reading the data from the file to your custom data type (2D array?) you need to create a `IplImage*` that is big enough to store this information.

IplImage* cv_data_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(custom_data_height, custom_data_width), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

and after that, you'll have to iterate on `cv_data_img` copying the original data.

Once `cv_data_img` it's filled with the data, you can create the others `IplImage*` you'll need to store the result of `cvResize()`.

At the end, you can iterate on the resulting `IplImage*` and copy it back to your original data type (2D array) or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @karlphilip - In openCV , how would I open a text file, read say floating point values in it into some float array and then copy it to opencv - IplImage type variable? Any sample code.

Comment: @goldenmean ACK, I'll get back to you on that later, I'm at work right and really busy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#cv-mat-mat) wrapper on top of your custom data and then proceed to use it as an ordinary `Mat` object. The constructor you would use is:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

Comment: Also checkout the opencv pyramid functions.  This covers this use case nicely.